# SQL Server 2012 - Trigger: Operand type clash: int is incompatible with unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing an audit trigger which saves every change occurred in the table in another table. But I receive this error when I am trying to alter the `Users` table:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with unique identifier

The `Users` table contains a uniqueidentifier column, among others.

Here is the part of the code where the error occurs:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UsersLogger] 
ON [dbo].[Users] 
FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @audit_oldvalue sql_variant;
    DECLARE @audit_value sql_variant;
    DECLARE @audit_field varchar(100);
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(max) ;
    DECLARE @OutString varchar(max) ;
    DECLARE @converted_uid nvarchar(50);

    DECLARE @qid int ;
    DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128)  

    SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info()  

    IF @Cinfo = 0x55555  
         RETURN  

    DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        ELSE NULL -- Skip. It may have been a "failed delete".   
                    END)

    SET @OutString = '' 

    SELECT * 
    INTO #tempTrigT 
    FROM 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM deleted 
         WHERE @Action IN ( 'U', 'D')) A 
    UNION 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM inserted 
     WHERE @Action = 'I') 

    SET @sql = '' 

if @Action = 'U'
BEGIN
Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],0) = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],0) then ''''  
 else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +' 
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'Users' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'
set @ParmDefinition = '@OutString varchar(max) OUTPUT' 
set @sql = 'Select @OutString = '  
+ Substring(@sql,1 , len(@sql) -1) +  
' From dbo.Users i  ' 
+ ' inner join #tempTrigT d on 
i.id = d.id'  
exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @OutString OUT 

END

 DECLARE @Items VARCHAR(max)

 set @Items = @OutString;

 DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @Pos INT
 DECLARE @Loop BIT
 SELECT @Loop = CASE WHEN LEN(@OutString) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 WHILE (SELECT @Loop) = 1
 BEGIN
 SELECT @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @OutString, 1)
 IF @Pos > 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT @Item = SUBSTRING(@OutString, 1, @Pos - 1)
 SELECT @OutString = SUBSTRING(@OutString, @Pos + 1, LEN(@OutString) - @Pos)

IF (TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Item) is not null)
begin
    select @Item = convert(nvarchar(50), @Item)
end
```

Comment: and where exact in this code does the error occurs ?

Comment: dont know... most probably when the sql is executed but im not sure

Comment: you could debug it in SSMS

Comment: and you have all this in a trigger :O and its only a part of your trigger :O do you not like the application you are working on???

Comment: @M.Ali its not mine and I had to work it like this... didnt have an option

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? There are parts that seem to make no sense whatsoever, like checking if you can convert `@item` to a unique identifier (`IF (TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Item) is not null)`), then if you can converting it to `NVARCHAR(50)` - Considering that `@Item` is declared as `VARCHAR(50)` in the first place, I can't see any point in that whole bit.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that this is the code leading to the problem: {'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],0)} - by this, you force each column to be converted to int... try using '0' instead.

Comment: @Tyron78 can you tell me how I can write that? I wrote it like this but still the same problem IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '], '+str(0)+') then

Comment: Did you try IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],'0') ?

Comment: this code is building a string so I cant use single quotes... I tried that ...IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],'+'0'+') ... with no luck

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd blame it on

```
Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],0) = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],0) then ''''  
 else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +' 
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'Users' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'
```

It's because you're doing an `ISNULL` on a `UNIQUEIDENTIIFIER` column and setting the value to an INT.  You could change from `ISNULL(i.[ColumnName], 0)` to `ISNULL(i.[ColumnName], '')` however, that is assuming all the columns in your tables are string applicable datatypes. Otherwise, you could do some conditional logic on the replacement value for the `ISNULL` function by using the `[DATA_TYPE]` column in that table.

Comment: I think there is the problem indeed. But how I can check if the column is GUID?

Comment: In your `information_schema.columns` table, you have a `[DATA_TYPE]` column that will let you know whether a column is a `VARCHAR, INT, UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`etc.  EDIT: Take it back, really depends on what you're trying to do, if you only need to overcome the error then set the `0` in `ISNULL` to a string i.e. `'0'` otherwise, you'll have to do some fancy switching based on datatypes. Hard to give advice when the purpose of the query is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: The purpose is to set empty string if the column contains null value. But when checks with GUID column it fails because it cant convert it to int. So I want to write a condition if there GUID column has empty values then set empty string

Comment: I meant the purpose of your code but it doesn't matter at this point, like others have mentioned, in your `ISNULL` function, wrap the replacement value in ''.  E.G. `Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  '],''0'')`

Comment: I did that but I get now:  Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. There is datetime column also...

Comment: Ah yeah, thought something like that might happen.  You'll have to do something like `Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name + '],' + CASE WHEN [DATA_TYPE] IN ('DATE', 'TIME', 'DATETIME') THEN '0' ELSE ''0'' END`